# How to import code list from .mdb to domain model in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, xml, import, uml

I have built an UML model in domain model structure in Enterprise Architect.
Now I want to import a couple of code lists to this model.

The problem is that the tables are in .mdb ArcGis workspace. I try to export tables from .mdb to XML document and then to import XML to Enterprise Architect- but the particular fields are in ESRI format type and I need them in enumeration (if the values is fixed) or codeList (if the values may be extended) to fulfil the terms of interoperability (INSPIRE).